# Derived Equivalences and Limits

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let $\{A_n\}_{n>0}$ be a family of $k$-algebras such that for each $n$ there is a $k$-algebra morphism $f_n:A_n \to A_{n+1}$ that induces a triangulated equivalence: (where $D(A_n)$ denotes the derived category of $A_n$)
$$ D(f^*) : D(A_{n+1}) \to D(A_n)   $$
where $f^*$ is the functor that considers an $A_{n+1}$-module as an $A_n$-module through $f$, and $D(f^*)$ is taking $f^*$ to derived categories pointwise.

Let $A=colim_{n>0}A_n$, does $D(A)$ has something to do with the categories $D(A_n)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only ring homomorphisms $f:R\to S$ such that $f^*$ is an equivalence of derived categories are isomorphisms. So the answer to your question is that yes, $D(A)$ does have something to do with the categories $D(A_n)$: they're all equivalent, but for a trivial reason.

[To prove my claim, suppose $f:R\to S$ is a ring homomorphism such that $f^*$ is an equivalence of derived categories. Clearly $X$ has homology concentrated in degree zero if and only if $f^*X$ does, so $f^*$ restricts to an equivalence between module categories (and so we can now forget about derived categories).

$f$ must be injective, as $\ker(f)$ annihilates $f^*X$, and so annihilates every $R$-module, since $f^*$ is an equivalence. So we can assume without loss of generality that $f$ is the inclusion of a subring, and so $f^*$ is just restriction.

The left adjoint of restriction is $-\otimes_RS$, and the unit of the adjunction (which must be an isomorphism of functors) applied to $R$ is just the $R$-module homomorphism $R\to R\otimes_RS$ given by $r\mapsto r\otimes 1$, which is just the inclusion $R\to S$. So $R=S$.]